# Grep zipped files for variables from .txt file

Tags: cygwin, xargs

I have zipped files like:

> 20191231_aaa.zip
>
> 20191231_bbb.zip
>
> 20191231_ccc.zip
>
> 20191230_aaa.zip
>
> 20191230_bbb.zip
>
> 20191230_ccc.zip
>
> 20191229_aaa.zip
>
> 20191229_bbb.zip
>
> 20191229_ccc.zip
>
> ...

I want to grep if files

> *aaa.zip and *bbb.zip

contains files:

- with specified word in name like 'house'
- for specified dates only like: 20191230, 20191220, 20191210 that are in dates.txt file in format:

> 20191230
>
> 20191220
>
> 20191210

I stacked with this:

`ls | xargs grep dates.txt | unzip -l | grep house`

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, below should work:

```
ls *.zip | fgrep -f dates.txt  | xargs -I{F} sh -c 'unzip -l {F} | grep -q house && echo FOUND: {F}'
```

DO note that above is a simplification, assuming "clean" `*.zip` filenames i.e. without spaces nor quotes.

Distilling it:

- `ls *.zip | fgrep -f dates.txt` will filter the file list using `dates.txt` as `fgrep` patterns
- `| xargs -I{F} sh -c '...'` will use each line read (*filename*.zip) to execute `sh -c '...'` where the `...` shell snippet will refer to each *filename*.zip as `{F}`